# Local variable is modifying the value of an unrelated variable

Tags: c, memory, overflow

I've been working with a little code to add a member into one array, when I try to make some changes to the code, I realized that the expected output was not correct (the modified array is not showing out). Debugging I saw that the declaration of the `int i` as a global variable instead of within the `for`loop do the expected output.

However, I found the problem was related to the variable `n` for some reason is modify inside the `while (j >= k)` when the variable `int i` is declared as the initialization of the for loop; but I can't figure it out why this is happening. If someone can help me to understand what and why is this happening, I'll be very thankful

This is my code which does the expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int LA[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
    int item = 10, k = 3, n = sizeof(LA)/sizeof(LA[0]);
    int j = n;
    int i;

    printf("n  = %d\n",n);
    printf("The original array elements are :\n");

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }
    printf("n  = %d\n",n);
    n = n + 1;
    printf("n  = %d\n",n);
    while( j >= k) {
        LA[j+1] = LA[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    printf("n  = %d\n",n);
    LA[k] = item;

    printf("The array elements after insertion :\n");
    printf("n = %d\n",n);
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }
}
```

This is my expected output:

```
n  = 5
The original array elements are :
LA[0] = 1
LA[1] = 3
LA[2] = 5
LA[3] = 7
LA[4] = 8
n  = 5
n  = 6
n  = 6
The array elements after insertion :
n = 6
LA[0] = 1
LA[1] = 3
LA[2] = 5
LA[3] = 10
LA[4] = 7
LA[5] = 8
```

This is my code which does NOT the expected output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int LA[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
    int item = 10, k = 3, n = sizeof(LA)/sizeof(LA[0]);
    int j = n;

    printf("n  = %d\n",n);
    printf("The original array elements are :\n");

    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }
    printf("n  = %d\n",n);
    n = n + 1;
    printf("n  = %d\n",n);
    while( j >= k) {
        LA[j+1] = LA[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
    printf("n  = %d\n",n);
    LA[k] = item;

    printf("The array elements after insertion :\n");
    printf("n = %d\n",n);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("LA[%d] = %d \n", i, LA[i]);
    }
}
```

This is my unexpected output:

```
n  = 5
The original array elements are :
LA[0] = 1
LA[1] = 3
LA[2] = 5
LA[3] = 7
LA[4] = 8
n  = 5
n  = 6
n  = 0
The array elements after insertion :
n = 0
```

Why the variable `n` is been modified depending on the declaration of `int i`?

Comment: You are doing out-of-bounds access on the array `LA` which is **undefined behaviour**. Arrays don't *expand* automatically in C when you append more values.

Comment: Specifically, the first time you execute `LA[j+1] = LA[j];` `j` is `n`, so both sided are out of range.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is uninteresting; there is no way to explain why it does work (it's an accident) or doesn't work (it's not surprising).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because speculating about what undefined behaviour should or should not do is futile.  Anything is permissible.